# Vue re-render of one component breaks rendering of other

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I have two components which display different information on the same data object. The object is placed in the store. Both components subscribe store actions to detect changes and re-render.

Component A is a child of Component B.

**Component A**

```
// used to track changes; refs.example is used to influence rendered DOM elements
const refs: {
  example?: Exercise,
} = reactive({
  example: undefined,
})

// subscribe to changes of selected
store.subscribeAction({
  after: (action) => {
    if (!subscribedActions.includes(action.type)) return
    // selected was altered, set example to trigger re-render
    refs.example = store.getters['selected'] as Example
  },
})
```

**Component B**

```
// Analog to component A
```

When `selected` is altered by an action, both `refs.example` are set and the components re-render. Component A re-renders before B.
Yet: Once B re-renders, Component A is rendered again as if its `refs.example` was `undefined` (if the setting of `refs.example` in Component B is delayed by `setTimeout`, Component A renders normally until Component B's `refs.example` is set). Though, if Component A is delayed until B has re-rendered, Component A never renders normally.

If B renders after A, there is a short a time when both components render normally. Component A is rendered "as undefined" at the end of this part of

**Vue's source code**

```js
function flushJobs(seen) {
  isFlushPending = false;
  isFlushing = true;
  if ((process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')) {
      seen = seen || new Map();
  }
  flushPreFlushCbs(seen);
  // Sort queue before flush.
  // This ensures that:
  // 1. Components are updated from parent to child. (because parent is always
  //    created before the child so its render effect will have smaller
  //    priority number)
  // 2. If a component is unmounted during a parent component's update,
  //    its update can be skipped.
  queue.sort((a, b) => getId(a) - getId(b));
  // conditional usage of checkRecursiveUpdate must be determined out of
  // try ... catch block since Rollup by default de-optimizes treeshaking
  // inside try-catch. This can leave all warning code unshaked. Although
  // they would get eventually shaken by a minifier like terser, some minifiers
  // would fail to do that (e.g. https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1610)
  const check = (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')
      ? (job) => checkRecursiveUpdates(seen, job)
      : NOOP;
  try {
      for (flushIndex = 0; flushIndex < queue.length; flushIndex++) {
          const job = queue[flushIndex];
          if (job && job.active !== false) {
              if ((process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') && check(job)) {
                  continue;
              }
              // console.log(`running:`, job.id)

              // COMPONENT A IS RENDERED AS UNDEFINED HERE
              callWithErrorHandling(job, null, 14 /* SCHEDULER */);
          }
      }
  }
...
```

Any ideas on the issue and its solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not know why this problem occured, I found a way to react to changes of a single object in store in two different components: Make use of store getters and `computed()`:

**Component A**

```js
const refs: {
  example?: Exercise,
} = reactive({
  example: computed(() => store.getters['examples/selected'] as Exercise),
})
```

The same code could be used in Component B. Alternatively, since B is a child of A, A could pass the `refs` down to B.